# macOS: PQconnectdb failing with "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"

Tags: c, postgresql, macos, linker, homebrew

I have a very basic C program just trying to connect to my locally running postgres server.

I don't think it is relevant to this issue, but I know the server is active and running with these credentials as I have connected to it with java code.

Below is the full source.

```
#include <libpq-fe.h>

PGconn *dbconn;

int main (void){
    dbconn = PQconnectdb("user=andrew passwd=andrew dbname=postgres");
}
```

Running this with

```
gcc postgreConnection.c
```

outputs

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PQconnectdb", referenced from:
      _main in postgreConnection-842958.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I downloaded libpq via homebrew.

I know I'm correctly hitting the "include" header because if I change the program to include a typo in the PQConnectdb call, such as:

```
#include <libpq-fe.h>

PGconn *dbconn;

int main (void){
    dbconn = PQconnectdbs("user=andrew passwd=andrew dbname=postgres");
}
```

I get the output of

```
postgreConnection.c:7:14: error: implicit declaration of function 'PQconnectdbs' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    dbconn = PQconnectdbs("user=andrew passwd=andrew dbname=postgres");
             ^
postgreConnection.c:7:14: note: did you mean 'PQconnectdb'?
/usr/local/include/libpq-fe.h:264:16: note: 'PQconnectdb' declared here
extern PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
               ^
postgreConnection.c:7:12: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'PGconn *' (aka 'struct pg_conn *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    dbconn = PQconnectdbs("user=andrew passwd=andrew dbname=postgres");
           ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```
gcc --version
```

output is

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Most questions I see related to this "symbols not found for architecture x86_64" seem more involved. I'm guessing my issue might actually be much simpler. I appreciate any advice on how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: You forgot to **link** in the library, presumably `-lpq`

Comment: That got it to compile successfully. Thank you so much brother.

Comment: @Antii, do you know of a good document that explains why the link variable name would be "pq"? I'm having a hard time understanding how I could have deduced that. I appreciate your help.

Edit: Looking here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html , I see -l library links a certain library. Should I be able to assume it is pq simply because the import is "<libpq...>"? Is this really the pattern for deducing libraries to link?

I went through the libpq-fe.h file hoping to see some declaration of "pq" as a library, but there is not one.

Comment: There is none, you need to know or look for the library file in the library directories or so. In case of PostgreSQL, the Unix/Linux compilation is detailed [in its documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/libpq-build.html)

Comment: Understood, thanks so much your help and the link.